# How can i add the above bar in a html template

Tags: html

[image]

Please I can't find the code to put this bar in a HTML template

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Check Bootstrap navbar in mobile view

Comment: What have you tried so far? Like already mentioned, Stackoverflow and it's users is here to help but not to write your code.

Answer (score -1):

this is a hamburger icon and is activated when the screen is too small you can do it by using bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/